# container creat error starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339

Tags: linux, docker, ldap

I installed ldap with docker and I now want to install phpkdapadmin with docker but when I try to create the container like this:

```
sudo docker run --name phpldapadmin -p 2226:443 --volume /ceph/docker/phpldapadmin/config:/container/service/phpldapadmin/assets/config/config.php --hostname phpldapadmin-service --link openldap:ldap-host --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=ldap-host --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.0
```

I get the following error message:

```
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/ceph/docker/phpldapadmin/config\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/71bdf95293b88ca0057943d91109d7afa51cc6388592000c8f3b520692249187/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/71bdf95293b88ca0057943d91109d7afa51cc6388592000c8f3b520692249187/merged/container/service/phpldapadmin/assets/config/config.php\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
```

Comment: It seems /ceph/docker/phpldapadmin/config does not exist on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In volume mappings you are specifying in host directory to mount a folder, and for container you are telling it that it should be a file like `config.php`. You can modify the volume mount by specifying `--volume /ceph/docker/phpldapadmin/config:/container/service/phpldapadmin/assets/config/`.

With this configuration, you need to have config file inside host at `/ceph/docker/phpldapadmin/config`